# How can I update attributes with a link in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to update attributes in a data table called "rang" from `0` to `1` using a link.

I have an action:

```
def ready
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  @task.update_attributes(:ready => '1')
  @task.save
  redirect_to :action => :index  
 end
```

And a link:

```
<%= link_to 'READY', { :action => :ready, :id => task.id } %>
```

But nothing happens.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So the record wasn't changed? Were there any errors on the logs? Also, I think update_attributes calls save, so no need for @task.save

Comment: Thanx for answers. When i click on link i dont get "ready" action i get "show" action of some reason (((

Answer (score 2):

Try :

in `routes.rb`

```
  resources :tasks do
      member do
        get 'ready'
      end
    end
```

Then link like:

```
<%= link_to 'READY', ready_task_url(task.id) %>
```